Unwanted sawtooth on LDO output
I'm using an LT3507A, which takes 12V to generate 1.2V,1.8V, and 3.3V on its switching regulators(primarily for an FPGA), as well as using the 4th LDO regulator to generate 1.8V for the 3 ADCs I have (LTC2258) - which uses a NPN transistor to regulate the 3.3V down to 1.8V.
Below is a schematic of the power generation

I'm facing an issue that, sometimes, unpredictably, the V1P8ADC line is completely unstable. Sometimes it is immediately after power up, especially if the PCB is already warm, and sometimes it takes hours, minutes, or days to show up. Below is a picture of the waveform on V1P8ADC acting normally.

And acting abnormally - this pattern will continue as long as the circuit is powered.

As seen, the oscillation is ~800mVpp, and has a frequency of ~12kHz.
If helpful, the next 2 images are of the V3P3 line, and the VC2 pin of the regulator, respectively.


The circuit is stable in LTSpice - but of course I can't reasonably simulate days worth of time - only simulating up to a few hundred milliseconds.
I have tried changing out the resistor and capacitors on the VC2 pin, to no effect. I'm unsure if the oscillation on V3P3 is because of the LDO sawtooth, or causing it. I have tried both increasing and decreasing the capacitance on the V1P8ADC, and it simply changes the frequency of the sawtooth.
When researching LDO instability, nothing I've read looks quite like this. I was hoping someone here would have an idea as to what's going on, or, could point me to a resource describing this issue.
Edit: Is it a coincidence that the frequency seen is within ~15% of the VC2 RC characteristic frequency? (13.8kHz)

Is the strange symbol for Q7 FZT653 only because two pins are connected to the collector?

That is correct, yes.

Is this a one-off or a problem with multiple boards? What is the loading when you observe issues/no issues? Why are your loop compensation networks different from the datasheet circuits?

It could be a loading issue, what are your loads, do they vary or are they constant? Did you size each inductor and capacitor for each loading channel?

The loading is identical when observing issues, versus not. V1P8ADC goes to VDD on 3x LTC2258 (OVDD is powered by the 1.8V switching regulator).
The loading is as constant as the VDD loading is. As the ADCs are constantly transmitting from power up.

@Spehro'speff'Pefhany - as for why the compensation is different, I don't have a great answer - but I will modify the board to match that in the datasheet and report back. Do you think the varying VC2 and 3V3 is whats causing the issue? Not the other way around?

@zbaltzer I doubt it, but it's a bit strange that 3V3 is changing so much. If this is a one-off issue I would suspect a bad connection, perhaps R232.

The rise time on V1P8ADC is around 10µs, with dV=0.8V and 10µF cap on the output (and probably other decoupling caps) we have i=C dv/dt = 0.8A.
So the LDO is dumping a lot more current than it is supposed to (the datasheet says "stable up to 300mA").
It is probably more, you can estimate it with a more precise measurement of rise time and knowledge of the sum of all decouping caps on the output. This large current spike to charge the output caps on V1P8ADC should be enough to explain the ripple on V3P3, so V3P3 is most likely innocent.
The scope shows an average value for V1P8ADC which is too high, also it looks like it overshoots the 1V8 target. This looks like the LDO is oscillating. I guess due to too much open loop gain due to the pass transistor's gm increasing at high current or something like that. The datasheet doesn't say much about the LDO's characteristics.
It's annoying to debug an intermittent issue like this, it would be nicer to be able to trigger it at will to debug it. So to confirm this is indeed a LDO issue you can connect a load on the output that will pull too much current and bring V1P8ADC down. For example you can connect a discharged 1µF MLCC to the output, that should draw a current spike large enough to trigger the oscillation, without the risk of burning the output transistor.
If that "works" then I guess you'll have to figure out how to compensate the LDO...

Thank you very much - and sure enough - it is reproducible by momentarily shorting V1P8ADC to ground. As for compensating the LDO TI suggests choosing the correct output capacitor/ESR seems to be the way to go. I'll try adding some tantalums and removing the ceramics to see if the response is any better.

Excellent! It's probably not showing at startup due to soft start smoothing things up. 0.1 ohm SMD resistance in series with 10µF MLCC makes a substitute for tantalum cap ;) Also maybe tweaking or removing the 33pF cap in the LDO feedback would have an effect

Problem: excess Ripple, instability
Cause: Poor/missing low ESR load caps (std e-caps 10x higher )
SW2 out is a SMPS. The other outputs are LDO's.

SMPS need lower ESR caps to reduce ripple.  20 mohm 150 uF is possible.
LDO's must not block all feedback, and LDOs lack load pulses to easily sense errors. So for FET LDOs, ESR * C = Tau must be higher than slew rate of error amp but not too high. Follow datasheet.

If you have ever tried to generate a single stage sawtooth signal, you realize the driver is an impulse (narrow pulse width spike current).
This can happen from hysteresis when ESR on the load caps cause a spike voltage to turn off current quickly after being applied instead of integrating the current. However at light loads, the Q rises sharply and skipping pulses is necessary or a 5~10% preload.
Low ESR e-Caps are typically approaching Tau=ESR*C = 1~20us for most.
Using five (5) 100 uF 6.3V caps increases C x 5 and reduces ESR by 5 thus reducing Tau by 1/25 Ohm.
Voltage ripple is I x ESR=800 mV in your plot.
Iavg = d.f. * Ipk  = 1/9 Ipk

Consider the Schmitt trigger oscillator where % hysteresis * RC determines the frequency period. Your correlation is correct due to ESR and the current sense threshold.
Tau varies with size, material, Dk of dielectric and reduces with higher DC rating.
Consider low  ESR
220 uF 10V 160 mOhm, /5 = 34 mOhm,  6.3 x 8 mm
Cap Tau= 35.2 us
Ultra low ESR Polymer e-Cap
150 uF 6.3V 20 mohm
Cap Tau = 3 us

So the suggestion is to replace the output caps on V1P8ADC with ultra low ESR caps? The only reason why I'd challenge this is that most literature suggests the opposite - that a cap with an ESR of ~1 Ohm is best for LDO regulation?

This is not an LDO. it pulses current so it must have ripple.  In a FET LDO if there is no ripple feedback it is unstable so ESR is necessary. Not so with old BJT linear regs. So Tau on FET LDO's determine phase margin and BW of error correction depending on GBW.

Actually, outputs 1 through 3 are all switching supplies; only output 4 is an LDO.

TY @Hearth  do you agree with my experience?
